# Splitting SQL column name and if any from their aliases using Regex [PHP]

Tags: php, sql, regex, alias

Using Regex I want to separate the column names (if any) from their aliases. As I mentioned below, I created an expression but it does not work without quotes.

Thank you !

```
(?<nameFull>               #nameRegex
 (?<name>[^"'`]+)          #name
 (?<nameQoute>["'`]+)?      #name Qoute
)
(?<aliasFull>               #aliasRegex
 \s+                        #before Alias WhiteSpace
 (?<AS>AS\s+)?              #AS Is match or Not match
 (?<aliasQoute>["'`])?      #alias Qoute
 (?<alias>[^"'`]+)          #alias
)?
```

You can also see the test I made with [this link](https://regex101.com/r/24UDyY/2).

Comment: So what you need is from a query like `SELECT test as test2 FROM table`, you need test and test2 selected?

Comment: @gaganshera I need column names and (if any)from their aliases.

Ex:

 `columnname2` AS `alias2`  =  "name"=>"columnname2", "alias"=>"alias2"

`columnname1`  =  "name"=>"columnname1"

columnname3 =  "name"=>"columnname3"

columnname4 as alias4 =  "name"=>"columnname4", "alias"=>"alias4"

columnname andisalias =  "name"=>"columnname", "alias"=>"andisalias "

Comment: @gaganshera The desired regex input and output image : [link](http://imgur.com/a/Atpey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex matching your needs :

`^\W?(?<table>[\w-]+\.)?(?<name>[\w-]+)\W?(\W+as\W+)?(?<alias>[\w-]+)?\W?$`

[Test this regular expression online](https://regex101.com/r/FxoJfn/3)

**PHP snippet**

```
$re = "/^\W?(?<table>[\w-]+\.)?(?<name>[\w-]+)\W?(\W+as\W+)?(?<alias>[\w-]+)?\W?$/i";

$array = [
    "columnam-e as myalias",
    "table.columnam-e as myalias",
    '"column" AS "mycolumn"',
    "'column' AS 'mycolumn'",
    "'table.column' AS 'mycolumn'",
    "`column` AS `mycolumn`",
    "columnam-e mycolumn",
    "colunmanesingle"
];

foreach ($array as $i => $value) {

    preg_match($re, $value, $matches);

    $name = $matches['name'];
    $table = NULL;
    $alias = NULL;

    if(array_key_exists('table', $matches)) {
      $table =  $matches['table'];
    }
    if(array_key_exists('alias', $matches)) {
      $alias =  $matches['alias'];
    }

    printf("%s\r=> table: %s, name: %s, alias: %s\r\r", $value, $table, $name, $alias);
}
```

[Test this PHP snippet online](https://repl.it/HQoh/1)

Comment: Hi!

It is not valid for text that has only the column name in your example. Thank you for your reply. I solved the problem. Solve [link](https://regex101.com/r/rfOMF9/1) is here.

Comment: Yup, It was a quick answer to help you. I'll update with a complete solution once I have some time ^^

Comment: Thank you for taking care of the problem ^^

Comment: Tablo adını sütun adından ayırmak için bir güncelleme yaptım. İncelemek isterseniz [link](https://regex101.com/r/rfOMF9/2) ^^

Comment: @MahsumUREBE Here is my final answer with an optimized regex (I tried to simplified yours which was already working ^^) and a sample PHP snippet. Have fun ;)

Comment: Thanks! I made an update to separate the table name from the column name. If you want to review [link](https://regex101.com/r/rfOMF9/2) ^^

Comment: @MahsumUREBE I've updated my answer to also match column prefixed with `tablename.`. This is my final answer, I think it match all your needs. If you think it answered your question, consider to accept it in order to help other people : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work